# Exiting a loop in a definition

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am using a Raspberry Pi 3B+ to control some motors based on inputs from a keypad. I am using the pad4pi library, and have set up a definition to handle the key presses. I should note that I am very new to Python.

I have tried putting returns and breaks in various spots but they either give a syntax error or continue as if I had pressed the button again, (effectively acting the same as if the return was not there.)

I have tried multiple things like:

```
elif (key=="8"): #-y
    print('y-')
    GPIO.output(yp, False)
    GPIO.output(yn, True)
    time.sleep(.01)
    GPIO.output(yp, False)
    GPIO.output(yn, False)
    return
```

or:

```
elif(key=="6"): #+x
    for t in range(5):
        print('x+')
        GPIO.output(xp, True)
        GPIO.output(xn, False)
    GPIO.output(xp, False)
    GPIO.output(xn, False)
    print('exit')
    return
```

but return and break seem to return to after the if function, the print line in the first one and the for line in the second.

I'm using the command line for feedback. For the second example what I'm expecting is:

```
x+
x+
x+
x+
x+
exit
```

but what I get is

```
x+
x+
x+
x+
x+
exit
x+
x+
x+
x+
...
```

Edit:
Here is the main code where the function is called:

```
#main loop
while(True):
    keypad.registerKeyPressHandler(move)
```

and here is how it is defined:

```
def move(key):
  if (key=="2"): #+y
    print('y+')
...
```

After that it is just elifs as shown above until the end:

```
  else:
    return
  return
```

And that's basically all the relevant code I believe.
Please let me know if you need more.
Edit 2:
Here is some code that recreates the issue:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from pad4pi import rpi_gpio
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
import time
from time import sleep

#y control
yp = 24;
yn = 26;
GPIO.setup(yp, GPIO.OUT) #+y
GPIO.setup(yn, GPIO.OUT) #-y

#keypad inputs
KEYPAD = [
        ["1","2","3","A"],
        ["4","5","6","B"],
        ["7","8","9","C"],
        ["*","0","#","D"]
]

COL_PINS = [31, 33, 35, 37]
ROW_PINS = [32, 36, 38, 40]
factory = rpi_gpio.KeypadFactory()
factory.create_4_by_4_keypad
keypad = factory.create_keypad(keypad=KEYPAD, row_pins=ROW_PINS, col_pins=COL_PINS)

def move(key):
  if (key=="8"): #-y
    print('y-')
    GPIO.output(yp, False)
    GPIO.output(yn, True)
    time.sleep(.01)
    GPIO.output(yp, False)
    GPIO.output(yn, False)
    return
  else:
    return

#main loop
while(True):
    keypad.registerKeyPressHandler(move)
#cleanup:
keypad.cleanup()
GPIO.cleanup()
```

Edit 3:
The error messages I get can mostly be chalked up to my inexperience in python. For example:

```
  if (key=="8"): #-y
    print('y-')
    GPIO.output(yp, False)
    GPIO.output(yn, True)
    time.sleep(.01)
    GPIO.output(yp, False)
    GPIO.output(yn, False)
    break
  else:
    return
```

gives:

```
> %Run recreate.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/python/recreate.py", line 36
    break
    ^
SyntaxError: 'break' outside loop
```

The only placement I tried that didn't give that error was:

```
    elif(key=="6"): #+x
        for t in range(5):
            print('x+')
            GPIO.output(xp, True)
            GPIO.output(xn, False)
            break
        GPIO.output(xp, False)
        GPIO.output(xn, False)
        print('exit')
        return
```

which returns:

```
x+
exit
x+
exit
x+
exit
x+
exit
x+
...
```

Edit:
Found the fix!
Move
`keypad.registerKeyPressHandler(move)`
outside of main loop.

Comment: Can you post more of your code? If the second code block is in a loop, you might see it execute several times.

Comment: Please make a [mcve]. The root issue might not even have anything to do with Rasberry Pi or pad4pi. At very least, [edit] and add the full error messages.

Comment: Thank you both. New code has been added.

Comment: Can you show an example of a `break` where there is an error and the *exact* error text.

Comment: Thank you, it has been edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you don't need break or return?  If your `move()` function has a physical effect but no effect on your program's state, there might be no need to return a value.  Only use `return` if you want to pass something back to the calling context (if your program logged position as it went, for example). But Python is fine with functions that only have 'side-effects' (and `return` nothing).

Your `if, elif, elif, else`: sequence will execute once per keypress, and only the matching keypress actions will occur, and then move() will be called again by the next keypress.

`break` cuts out of a loop and jumps to the next executable instruction.

You might have been looking for the Python keyword [continue](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) which allows you to send control back to the head of the loop, but I think you don't need it when everything is in `if/elif/elif` blocks.

I haven't used the classes you're working with, but I would guess that you should move the registration of the Handler function `move` outside the `While` loop: you are just adding a set of instructions about what to do when a key is pressed to the keypad object, and you only need to do that once.  Your `while(True):` loop could just check a condition to `break` - check a sensor condition or a special key to stop execution. There is probably a more 'event driven' way of coding this, but I can't advise about it.

Comment: Thank you. I took your advice to clean up my code, but the issue was actually caused by the function being in the while(true) loop. Still, my code is much cleaner now.